# Why does my hostname append to itself?

Tags: flask, docker-swarm, flask-restful

I'm teaching myself how to turn API routes into micro-services, so I made a small project to do this. I'm using Flask (and Docker), because the "monolithic" product which I'm tasked with turning into a micro-service architecture uses Flask (for now). Full disclosure, I've never done this before, and neither has my senior developer, so I don't know where to start, so I'm picking a simple question, which is after some details, and it is ***boldly italicized*** on the bottom.

My routes are:

- `"/"`
- `"/foo"`
- `"/bar"`

Each of those has its own container. I build each container, (Which, when run on it's own, works, serving a page.), tagging each `hello-micro`, `foo-micro`, and `bar-micro`, and then do `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml micro-stack`. The stack deploys with no error or warning messages.

My entire project, which isn't very big, is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/NonCreature0714/learn-microservices).

Ideally, I browse to the `"/"` container, follow the link to `"/foo"`, then go to `"/bar"`, and am able to go to `"/"` from any point in the app.

`"/"` is serving on `0.0.0.0` - and the Dockerfile exposes port `80`. The docker-compose.yml binds `"/"` to 8080:80, so I access it via `0.0.0.0:8080`.

At "/" I have a link to 'home' which is just an href anchor to "". This, I think, ***should just reload 0.0.0.0:8080, but instead it links to 0.0.0.0:8080/0.0.0.0:8080.***

***What's going on here?***

Comment: I'm not sure Flask can do what you ask it to. Don't you need a reverse proxy of some sort in front to construct micro services the way you describe? Flask itself, the way I understand it, will always take up the root of a server:port URI.

Comment: @MichelMüller thank you -- I'll begin researching reverse proxies with flask.

Comment: most commonly used combo is AFAIK nginx + uwsgi for python based webapps. nginx can do reverse proxying, i.e. route from something like /foo to a host:port http network address.

Comment: @MichelMüller looking up nginx and other detail now, thanks!